# I have a table with 100000 numbers, and i have search for 11111,1111111111 in table with bisection method

Tags: c#, search, numbers, bisection

I am doing some examples for my exam next week. Here is my problem.

I filled the table with 100000 numbers. I need to search for 11111,1111111111 with bisection. I am not sure how bisection work, i know how to find it usual way, with loop.

There is my table.

```
double[] testi = new double[100000];
        Random naklj = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <testi.Length; i++)
        {
           testi[i] = Math.Round(naklj.NextDouble() * 100000, 10);
        }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Algorithm?

Comment: Bisection method usually refers to a tree structure.  So do you have a tree?

Comment: http://theflyingkeyboard.net/c-2/c-bisection-method/

Comment: You would start with a sorted set of numbers. Then take the middle number, is it higher or lower? Get the corresponding half of the set, find the middle number. Is it higher or lower? etc.

Comment: I posted my answer bellow, your sugestions helped me, so thank you. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, you helped me. Thank you

```
public static bool Bisekcija(double[] tab, double search)
    {
        int doKam = tab.Length - 1; // right limit in table
        int odKje = 0; //where do we start searching 
        int sred;  // index of middle
        while (odKje <= doKam) // searching until is over
    {
        sred = (odKje + doKam) / 2; // calculate index of middle
        if (tab[sred] < search)  //comapring data
            odKje = sred + 1; // 
        else
            if (tab[sred] > search)
            doKam = sred - 1; //new right limit
        else // podatka sta enaka, torej je tab[sred] == iskano
            return true; //return true if exist
    }

    return false; // return false if exist
}
```